# python multiples of 19

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been working on this for a few days now. I have looked at several tutorials and read in my book, I am very new to coding.

I am required to write this program

This program should prompt the user to enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200. Then, the program should analyze the input and display a response to each of the four possible results of the analysis. See sample runs below.

```
Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200 76
No, 76 is a multiple of 19 but it is not greater than 200
>>> 
Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200 55
55 is not over 200 and also is not a multiple of 19
>>> 
Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200 222
222 is over 200 but is not a multiple of 19
>>> 
Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200 380
Good input. 19 divides into 380 exactly 20 times
```

this is what I have so far

```
#promt user to enter an exact multiple of 19 that is larger than 200
#assign variable a to user input
def main () :
    random = int(input('Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200:'))

    number = random / 19


    if random > 200 :
        print('Good input 19 divides into', random , 'exactly' , number ,'times')


    if random % 19 == 0 or random <200:
        print('is a multiple of 19')

    else:
        print('is not a multiple of') 


main ()
```

i can get the program to spit out the line for the user inputting 380 but I am at a loss as far as how to write up the other outputs. Help would be awesome!!!

Comment: Ah, the ole' fizzbuzz test. (This should be enough to help figure it out without handing it on a silver platter)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Heres what I worked out, though I think Im doing his homework...:

```
def main():
    try:
        random = int(input('Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200:')) 
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a number")
        return  

    number = random % 19 #if number==0 it's divisible by 19

    if random <= 200: #checks to see if the number is less than 200

        if number == 0: #if the num is divisible by 19 but less than 200

            print("Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200. No, {0} is a multiple of 19 but it is not greater than 200".format(random))

        else: #if the num is not divisible by 19 ant it's less than 200

            print("Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200. No, {0} is not over 200 and also is not a multiple of 19".format(random))

        return

    if number != 0: #if the number is over 200 buy not divisible by 19

        print("Enter an exact multiple of 19 that is greater than 200. No, {0} is over 200 but is not a multiple of 19".format(random))
        return
    #every other possibility: divisible by 19 and over 200
    print('Good input 19 divides into {0} exactly {1} times'.format(random, random/19))

main()
```

Comment: Please explain then code instead of just doing their homework for them.

Comment: @brittmoe09 do your own homework next time! Fell free to give me a check mark for helping you if I solved your problem:)